# Python - selenium webdriver-switch to captcha frame and select audio

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm a newbie who is trying to learn python programming. As a self-taught in programming I try to learn python by working on a project. I try to make an automated script which can access a page, do some actions and resolve audio captcha. At the moment I'm stuck at switching frames and select audio from captcha frame.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVNnD.jpg - switching to audio captcha

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yh7u.jpg - i want to access this for moment

I put the code here. I don't get any errors or something is just after clicking "I'm not a robot", nothing happens anymore.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("website.com")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),    "ClickHere!")]').click()

driver.find_element_by_name("address").click()

address = driver.find_element_by_name("address")
address.send_keys("xGDnjCuYNe52ieJagKnBwhUepPsPd6jGhY")

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 3)
time.sleep(2)
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
action.perform()

recaptchaFrame = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME ,'iframe'))
)

frameName = recaptchaFrame.get_attribute('iframe')
driver.switch_to_frame(frameName)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")

time.sleep(2)

frameName = ActionChains(driver)
frameName.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(3)
frameAction.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

## And now the program should automatically switch to audio captcha

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google reCAPTCHA technology is made to be "tough on bots, easy on humans", you can read more about it [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/). Here's a snippet from the website:

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and
>   abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive
>   CAPTCHAs to keep automated software from engaging in abusive
>   activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users
>   pass through with ease.

My guess is Google is identifying your automated program as a bot somehow and not letting you go through.

Comment: Good to know. I'll try to do it in other ways. Thank you for your time.